# Play animation when click on each player with in maincamera unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

I have 3 gameobjects (`player1`, `player2`, `player3`). I attached a script "playerscript" to these game objects.  In the main camera, I have added another script called "testscript". Clicking on a player should play the animation.  For that, I need to call the `update()` of "testscript.cs" in maincamera to the `onMouseDown()` of "playerscript.cs".

*testscript.cs*:

```
public class testscript : MonoBehaviour {
public bool selected;
public GameObject player1;
public GameObject player2;
public GameObject player3;

void Update () {
    //animation PickRightAndLeft
    player1.animation.Play("PickRightAndLeft");
}
```

*playersscript.cs*:

```
public class Playersscript : MonoBehaviour {
     void OnMouseDown () {
         Debug.Log (gameObject.name);
      }
}
```

Comment: when i click on the "player1" it should displays its corresponding animation ,along with that how can i identify the animation(these animations code are written in testscrip.cs) of clicked player.

Answer (score 1):

so if i understand you correctly you actually have the test script attached to the player object not the camera?

if so you'll need to make sure you have done 3 things:

1. ensure the player game objects have `Animation` components
2. get the Animation component into a variable in your script ( i prefer to do this when accessing objects from across scripts but it may not be always necessary )

   `public anim = GameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();`
3. on mouse down of the `testscript` you can now play the named animation

   `OnMouseDown(){ anim.Play("walk"); }`

---

you want to access your camera's script component from within the player scripts.  once you have access to that, as long as the scope is set properly, you should have access to calling the methods from the other script.

so within your `Playerscript.cs` : `OnMouseDown()` method you will want to start somewhere like this:

```
YOURCAMERA.GetComponent<YOURSCRIPT>().YOURMETHOD();
```

this structure should access the camera, look for the script youve attached to it and then attempt to call a method defined within that script.

obviously you may want to be more specific about your camera, the script, and method names.  and i would recommend to use an exact reference to your camera in case your game is using multiples - which will cause this to fail from the get go. (replace Camera.main, with your actual camera).

you will also need to reference your script name and the method you wish to call like so:

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<testscript>().Update();
```

### reference material

[GameObject.GetComponent documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

[Unity "accessing other scripts"](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html)

Comment: its ok... but when i click on the "player1" it should displays its corresponding animation ,along with that how can i identify the animation(these animations code are written in testscrip.cs) of clicked player.

Comment: i wrote this answer based on the fact you stated in your question: `In the main camera i have added another script called" testscript".`  if you could please provide more information and correct any discrepancies ill take a second look

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a more modular option than referencing your main camera is simply adding a public field to hold a reference to TestScript. Also you should change the name of the `Update` method, as it has a special meaning in Unity:

```
 public class Playersscript : MonoBehaviour 
 {
   public TestScript MyTestScript; //Set this in the inspector
   void OnMouseDown () 
   {
       Debug.Log (gameObject.name);
       MyTestScript.MyUpdate();
   }

}
```